# How do I find a Form_ID for hook_form_FORM_ID_alter?

Tags: 8, forms

I want to alter the form for a content type I created for videos.  The type is called Videos.  How would I use hook_form_alter to alter the form to create the content?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The form ID is used as the id attribute on the form when it renders.

For content types the pattern is also predictable:  `node-[TYPE_NAME]-form`.  So in your case you're looking for:  `hook_form_node_videos_form_alter()`.

Another way to handle it is to use the main `hook_form_alter()` and check the $form_id parameter when you load the form you'd like to target.

Comment: i get syntax errors using - between node and videos and when i use _ it doesnt seem to be executing.  Can i simply add this hook to the video module or do i need my own module just to alter the video form? so my function looks like video_form_node_video_form_alter

Comment: Sorry I mistyped that - they should always be underscores.  Do NOT update the existing module as future updates to that module will overwrite your changes. Create your own module.

Comment: perfect that worked.  is that the same form for editing the node?

Comment: Yes, nodes have just one form used for both create and edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can also just look at the generated markup. the form_id is always present as a hidden form_element, so just search for "form_id" in the source code and you should find it. Make sure you're looking at the correct form wrapper, often there are multiple forms (e.g. search/signup/login blocks)

Answer (score 3):

Enable the development module then in your own .module file to get the form_id

`function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    dpm(form_id);//get the form_id
    dpm(form);//get the form
     }`

Save the file flush the cache and you can see the form_id.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8, navigate to the devel tab on the webform, click on render. Expand the variables and search for 'webform_id'. You can find the webform id here.